# Is there an equivalent to OPENROWSET in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, database-link, openrowset, dblink

Is there an equivalent to OPENROWSET in Oracle?

> From [OPENROWSET (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx):
>
> This method is an alternative to accessing tables in a linked server and is a one-time, ad hoc method of connecting and accessing remote data by using OLE DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*<sub>Answer provided by [John Eisbrener](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/39083/john-eisbrener) in a comment</sub>*

The effective equivalent is a [Database Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm).  Sadly there's not an identical equivalent to what `OPENROWSET` does in one Oracle command or statement.  You have to declare the db link first before accessing it.  If you don't want to edit a `tnsnames.ora` file, you can create the dblink using an [in-line statement](http://oracleblues.blogspot.com/2010/11/inline-database-link.html), which allows you to programmatically emulate `OPENROWSET` functionality.